# How to write application environment value of node list?

Tags: erlang

When using rebar for release, I have to set an environment variable. It is a node list. For example:

```
vm.args
# -zarah cluster_nodes ['zarah_slave_a@yus-iMac.local','zarah_slave_b@yus-iMac.local','emacs@yus-iMac.local']
```

But when running, the shell gives the error message:

```
＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊
{error_logger,{{2013,11,20},{10,47,28}},"application_controller: ~ts: ~ts~n",[["syntax error before: ","'.'"],"[zarah_slave_a@yus-iMac.local,zarah_slave_b@yus-iMac.local,emacs@yus-iMac.local]"]}
Erlang R16B02 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:fals
```

I think it is the problem cause by "." in the node name. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 3):

Add a double quote before the single quote and it will work.

```
-zarah cluster_nodes ["'zarah_slave_a@yus-iMac.local'","'zarah_slave_b@yusiMac.local'","'emacs@yus-iMac.local'"]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. But I have used configure file, and read the data and convert it to what I need, then set the environment variable. Thank you for your attention.